# Converting XML to CSV. Pandas to_csv is not writing some rows, but is writing others. Can't spot it

Tags: python, pandas, xml, csv, data-conversion

I am converting an XML to a CSV.

It is writing the rows well for some, but for others it's writing nothing.

Below is my code.  The rows that are writing are:

- Brand
- Line
- Name

The other rows are not.  You'll see in the productType I do a check and print to the console either `retail` or `usage` and this does print to the console for every item.  It's working.  however, it's just not writing data.   I'm totally stumped.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
# Importing the required libraries
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
import pandas as pd
  
productColumns = ["brand", "line", "name", "purpose", "retailPrice"]
rows = []
  
# Parsing the XML file
xmlparse = Xet.parse('xmlimportdata.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()

products = root.findall("productTableData")

for product in products:

    # make sure a product and not a service (P vs S)
    if product.find("productType").text == "P":        

        productBrand = product.find("Make")
        if productBrand is not None:
            productBrand = productBrand.text
        else:
            productBrand = "No Data"
        
        productLine = product.find("Category")
        if productLine is not None:
            productLine = productLine.text
        else:
            productLine = "No Data"
        
        productName = product.find("Name")
        if productName is not None:
            productName = productName.text
        else:
            productName = "No Data"

        productType = product.find("usageType")
        if productType is not None:
            if productType.text == "true":
                print('usage')
                productType = "usage"
            else:
                productType = "retail"
                print('retail')
        else:
            productType = "No Data"
        
        productSize = product.find("Size")
        if productSize is not None:
            productSize = productSize.text
        else:
            productSize = "No Data"
        
        productPrice = product.find("Retail")
        if productPrice is not None:
            productPrice = productPrice.text
        else:
            productPrice = "No Data"

        productId = product.find("ID")
        if productId is not None:
            productId = productId.text
        else:
            productId = "No Data"

        rows.append({"brand": productBrand,
                     "line": productLine,
                     "name": productName,
                     "type": productType,
                     "size": productSize,
                     "price": productPrice
                     })


# add data to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=productColumns)
  
# Writing dataframe to csv
# note the columns =  This little ripper will auto sort columns for us and place in correct order
df.to_csv('Converted-Products.csv', columns = productColumns, index = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `pandas` for this conversion. Leave the large library for data analysis. Simply `open` a text file and use `csv` package to `writerows`. And use a defined method to keep your code DRY-er (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself) with use of ternary operators (i.e., `if` and `else` on same line).

```py
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet

elementColumns = ["ID", "Make", "Category", "Name", "usageType", "Size", "Retail"]
productColumns = ["id", "brand", "line", "name", "purpose", "size", "retailPrice"]

def get_text(elem, colname):
    colElem = elem.find(colname)

    colText = colElem.text if colElem is Not None else "No Data"

    if col == "usageType" and colElem is Not None:
        colText = "usage" if colElem.text == "true" else "retail"
        
    return colText

# PARSE XML FILE
xmlparse = Xet.parse('xmlimportdata.xml')
root = xmlparse.getroot()
products = root.findall("productTableData")

# OPEN CSV FOR WRITING
with open("Output.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    # HEADERS
    writer.writerow(productColumns)

    # ROWS
    for product in products:
        if product.find("productType").text == "P":
            writer.writerow([
                get_text(product, col) 
                for col in elementColumns
            ])
```

Comment: Even though I figured it out I appreciate the work you put into your answer to help me learn more.  So I've marked it the correct answer.  Thank you for your time spent.

Answer (score 0):

Update!  I found it.  The rows.append was not appending the same names as the rows declared in the productColumns at the start.  As soon as I made them match, we got output.